# Flask-edits: AttributeError: 'TokenStream' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to test the flask-edits package (https://github.com/nathancahill/Flask-Edits)

Can anyone help with this error: AttributeError: 'TokenStream' object has no attribute 'next'

```
@app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        return render_template('test.html')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

The template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Haldane</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Test</p>

{% editable 'Section name' %}
    Python is a programming language that lets you work quickly and integrate systems more effectively.
{% endeditable %}

</body>
</html>
```

The error occurs here:

```
"""Jinja extensions to mark sections as editable
"""
import hashlib
from collections import OrderedDict
from jinja2.nodes import Output, Template, TemplateData
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class EditableExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['editable'])

    def parse(self, parser):
        _db = self.environment.edits

        # Skip begining node
        parser.stream.next()
```

The error:

```
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_edits/editable.py", line 18, in parse
parser.stream.next()
AttributeError: 'TokenStream' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Gist including the code:
https://gist.github.com/archienorman11/98993d66fc30283ba113f8a4f2b39669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Flask-Edits wants to support Python 3, this is a bug in Flask-Edits.  It should use the builtin [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to advance iterators: `next(parser.stream)`.  The method on the iterator changed from `next` to `__next__` between Python 2 and 3.  The builtin function works for both.